# What is the best way to delete bulk amount of rows in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, c#-4.0, sql-server-2008-r2

Here I am using a query,

```
"delete from Table where id in" ({0})", string.Join(",", Key.ToArray())
```

Is any other best way to speed up this process?

Note : I used indexes.

Example :

I used SQL profiller to traced it
query is:

> delete from [Table] where Key in (27267 , 27268 , 27269 , 27270 ,
>   27271 , 27272 , 27273 , 27274 , 27275 , 27276 , 27277 , 27278 , 27279
>   , 27280 , 27281 , 27282 , 27283 , 27284 , 27285 , 27286 , 27287 ,
>   27288 , 27289 , 27290 , 27291 , 27292 , 27293 , 27294 , 27295 , 27296
>   , 27297 , 27298 , 27299 , 27300 , 27301 , 27302 , 27303 , 27304 ,
>   27305 , 27306 , 27307 , 27308 , 27309 , 27310 , 27311 , 27312 , 27313
>   , 27314 , 27315 , 27316 , 27317 , 27318 , 27319 , 27320 , 27321 ,
>   27322 , 27323 , 27324 , 27325 , 27326 , 27327 , 27328 , 27329 , 27330
>   , 27331 , 27332 , 27333 , 27334 , 27335 , 27336 , 27337 , 27338 ,
>   27339 , 
>       27340 , 27341 , 27342 , 27343 , 27344 , 27345 , 27346 , 27347 , 27348 , 27349 , 27350 , 27351 , 27352 , 27353 , 27354 , 27355 , 27356
>   , 27357 , 27358 , 27359 , 27360 , 27361 , 27362 , 27363 , 27364 ,
>   27365 , 27366 , 27367 , 27368 , 27369 , 27370 , 27371 , 27372 , 27373
>   , 27374 , 27375 , 27376 , 27377 , 27378 , 
>       27379 , 27380 , 27381 , 27382 , 27383 , 27384 , 27385 , 27386 , 27387 , 27388 , 27389 , 27390 , 27391 , 27392 , 27393 , 27394 , 27395
>   , 27396 , 27397 , 27398 , 27399 , 27400 , 27401 , 27402 , 27403 ,
>   27404 , 27405 , 27406 , 27407 , 27408 , 27409 , 27410 , 27411 , 27412
>   , 27413 , 27414 , 27415 , 27416 , 27417 , 
>       27418 , 27419 , 27420 , 27421 , 27422 , 27423 , 27424 , 27425 , 27426 , 27427 , 27428 , 27429 , 27430 , 27431 , 27432 , 27433 , 27434
>   , 27435 , 27436 , 27437 , 27438 , 27439 , 27440 , 27441 , 27442 ,
>   27443 , 27444 , 27445 , 27446 , 27447 , 27448 , 27449 , 27450 , 27451
>   , 27452 , 27453 , 27454 , 27455 , 27456 , 
>       27457 , 27458 , 27459 , 27460 , 27461 , 27462 , 27463 , 27464 , 27465 , 27466 , 27467 , 27468 , 27469 , 27470 , 27471 , 27472 , 27473
>   , 27474 , 27475 , 27476 , 27477 , 27478 , 27479 , 27480 , 27481 ,
>   27482 , 27483 , 27484 , 27485 , 27486 , 27487 , 27488 , 27489 , 27490
>   , 27491 , 27492 , 27493 , 27494 , 27495 , 
>       27496 , 27497 , 27498 , 27499 , 27500 , 27501 , 27502 , 27503 , 27504 , 27505 , 27506 , 27507 , 27508 , 27509 , 27510 , 27511 , 27512
>   , 27513 , 27514 , 27515 , 27516 , 27517 , 27518 , 27519 , 27520 ,
>   27521 , 27522 , 27523 , 27524 , 27525 , 27526 , 27527 , 27528 , 27529
>   , 27530 , 27531 , 27532 , 27533 , 27534 , 
>       27535 , 27536 , 27537 , 27538 , 27539 , 27540 , 27541 , 27542 , 27543 , 27544 , 27545 , 27546 , 27547 , 27548 , 27549 , 27550 , 27551
>   , 27552 , 27553 , 27554 , 27555 , 27556 , 27557 , 27558 , 27559 ,
>   27560 , 27561 , 27562 , 27563 , 27564 , 27565 , 27566 , 27567 , 27568
>   , 27569 , 27570 , 27571 , 27572 , 27573 , 27574 , 27575 , 27576 ,
>   27577 , 27578 , 27579 , 27580 , 27581 , 27582 , 27583 , 27584 , 27585
>   , 27586 , 27587 , 27588 , 27589 , 27590 , 27591 , 27592 , 27593 ,
>   27594 , 27595 , 27596 , 27597 , 27598 , 27599 , 27600 , 27601 , 27602
>   , 27603 , 27604 , 27605 , 27606 , 27607 , 27608 , 27609 , 27610 ,
>   27611 , 27612 , 27613 , 27614 , 27615 , 27616 , 27617 , 27618 , 27619
>   , 27620 , 27621 , 27622 , 27623 , 27624 , 27625 , 27626 , 27627 ,
>   27628 , 27629 , 27630 , 27631 , 27632 , 27633 , 27634 , 27635 , 27636
>   , 27637 , 27638 , 27639 , 27640 , 27641 , 27642 , 27643 , 27644 ,
>   27645 , 27646 , 27647 , 27648 , 27649 , 27650 , 27651 , 27652 , 27653
>   , 27654 , 27655 , 27656 , 27657 , 27658 , 27659 , 27660 , 27661 ,
>   27662 , 27663 , 27664 , 27665 , 27666 , 27667 , 27668 , 27669 , 27670
>   , 27671 , 27672 , 27673 , 27674 , 27675 , 27676 , 27677 , 27678 ,
>   27679 , 27680 , 27681 , 27682 , 27683 , 27684 , 27685 , 27686 , 27687
>   , 27688 , 27689 , 27690 , 27691 , 27692 , 27693 , 27694 , 27695 ,
>   27696 , 27697 , 27698 , 27699 , 27700 , 27701 , 27702 , 27703 , 27704
>   , 27705 , 27706 , 27707 , 27708 , 27709 , 27710 , 27711 , 27712 ,
>   27713 , 27714 , 27715 , 27716 , 27717 , 27718 , 27719 , 27720 , 27721
>   , 27722 , 27723 , 27724 , 27725 , 27726 , 27727 , 27728 , 27729 ,
>   27730 , 27731 , 27732 , 27733 , 27734 , 27735 , 27736 , 27737 , 27738
>   , 27739 , 27740 , 27741 , 27742 , 27743 , 27744 , 27745 , 27746 ,
>   27747 , 27748 , 27749 , 27750 , 27751 , 27752 , 27753 , 27754 , 27755
>   , 27756 , 27757 , 27758 , 27759 , 27760 , 27761 , 27762 , 27763 ,
>   27764 , 27765 , 27766)

Here I am deleting 500 records, its takes 6553 milliseconds duration.

[image]

Comment: You should trace the db and see wha is going on.

Comment: @Sam : Trace output are added in the question.

Comment: You might want to ensure that all the references to this table are indexed, otherwise Sql Server needs to do a table scan of foreign key table(s) to see if the record can be deleted. Note: high number of reads suggests that this is the case.

Comment: @Nikola Markovinović : Yes I have 3 tables are mapped with this table, First I deleted both two and then i deleted this, I tried to use casecade but same time.

Comment: If not that, is there a delete trigger?

Comment: No, I didn't use triggers, I ll try. Thanks nikola

Comment: I didn't suggest to use trigger. I **asked** if there is one already. If there is none, and referencing tables are empty, I don't see what would produce 8 million reads.

Comment: ok thanks nikola.. now What I need to check?

Answer (score 1):

This option will likely speed up the *delete*, but may *not* speed up the overall SQL processing time.  So with that caveat...

You could first insert the keys you want to delete into a temporary variable (or temp table).  Then, you could use a join in the delete clause so you don't have to use an `IN` clause.  Ex.

```
DECLARE @MyTableVar table(id int)

INSERT INTO @MyTableVar (id) VALUES (27267)
//Repeat insert for other values, or use a different mechanism to insert keys
//into the temp table/table variable.
//Since that's not the focus of this question, I won't go into details on this
//portion.
...

DELETE FROM [your table]
FROM [your table] T1
INNER JOIN @MyTableVar T2
ON T1.id= T2.id
```

Obviously the Inserts will take time, so if you are concerned with the overall time of the transaction this may not help.  But if making the delete portion faster is the primary concern (to minimize lock time, for example), then this may still be useful.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189835.aspx for usage examples of a DELETE statement that includes a JOIN and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx for info on a table variable.